# Set background color for a specific x-range only

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the following example code to generate a simple plot:

```
# Import modules
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create 1D array with time values
t = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)

# Calculate 1D array with acceleration values
a = 10 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

# Create plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, a)

# Annotate plot
fig.suptitle("acceleration in the time-domain")
ax.set_xlabel("time [s]")
ax.set_ylabel("acceleration [g]")

# Set background color
ax.patch.set_facecolor('red')
ax.patch.set_alpha(0.2)

# Trigger display of plot window
plt.show()
```

The axes area of the resulting plot has a light red background color, as shown here:

[image: matplotlib result]

What I would like to achieve however is a plot in which the background is light red in the x-range 1.00 to 1.50 only (and white in the remaining x-range). Is this possible?

Comment: Use `.fill_between` or `axvspan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:

You can use the axvspan function  as such

```
ax.axvspan(1.0, 1.5, color='red')
```